# Copy selected item's text from select control html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select control with pre defined values and I want my users to be able to copy the selected item's text with CTRL + C

I don't want them to be able to change the text of the item (just select it with the mouse/keyboard)

here is a fiddle that shows the problem (I can't select the text of the selected item)

http://jsfiddle.net/5C3Q9/1/

```
<select>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select>
```

Can I do that without JS? 
if not how do i do that with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to mimick the behaviour you are after, with a bit of positioning magic and jQuery. The code is only tested on Chrome, so it might need a bit of tweaking to look good in all browsers. Also see the note at the bottom of the page for IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/FvFVJ/

The html is rather simple. Just add an `input` field next to your select and wrap both in a div. You can add the property `readonly` to the input field, to disable editing if you wish

---

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 21px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.wrap select {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrap input {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 0;
}

.wrap:after{
    content: "\25BE";
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -3px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Both elements are `position:absolute` inside the wrapper. Things to notice

1. The `select` element has `opacity:0` which makes it invisible but still clickable
2. The pseudo element `.wrap:after`, which acts as a dropdown arrow (*)
3. The `z-index` ordering, which puts the input on top of the select, expect of the corner
   which will act as the dropdown button
4. The widths need to be properly fixed, either in css (static) or by javascript (dynamic)

---

```
$(function () {
    $(".wrap").width($(".wrap select").width());
    $(".wrap input").width($(".wrap select").width() - 20);
    $(".wrap select").on("change", function () {
        var txt = $(this).find(':checked').text();
        $(".wrap input").val(txt);
    });
});
```

And finally some javascript to set the correct widths for our elements and update the input text everytime we choose a new value from the select.

---

(*) : The pseudo element will not work in IE7 or . A workaround is to use a background image for the `.wrap` element

Comment: That's just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5vssh2d2/1/)
As opposed to @Dogoku's answer, this is more direct, you don't need to first select your text. Just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> whilst the `<select>` has focus and it will copy the selected `<option>`'s text to your clipboard.
This'll work in modern browsers (including IE>7) without jQuery or funky css.

```
//to be ran on keydown, which occurs before clipboard copy
function copyWatch(e) {
    e = e || event;
    if (
        //not ctrl+C
        (!(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == '67')) ||
        //nothing selected
        (this.selectedIndex < 0)
    )
        return;

    //create selectable text
    var copyEl = document.createElement('textarea');
    copyEl.innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

    //hide it, but in a way the browser thinks is clickable
    //(no visibility:hidden, display:none)
    copyEl.style.position = 'absolute';
    copyEl.style.left = '-9999px';

    var that = this;
    //add a call back for after the ctrl+c is completed
    copyEl.onkeyup = function() {
        //remove the extraneous element
        copyEl.parentNode.removeChild(copyEl);
        //return focus to the select
        that.focus();
    };

    //add it to the document, and highlight all the text in the textarea,
    //ready for the ctrl+c copy event to fire
    document.body.appendChild(copyEl).select();
}
```

Comment: I did this because I didn't like the other solution, which introduced a text input that you can highlight and messes with the usability (tab-index & up-down arrows for selecting), although it would be nifty for editable options (but I bet there's a dedicated jQuery plugin for that though, which would have better support)

Comment: Coming back to this questions 3 years older and hopefully wiser, I'd choose your approach as well :)

Comment: one of the great things about SO. I dont doubt the answer will be improved by another newcomer later down the line :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to mark the text of a option element. Copy text into clipboard without flash is impossible, too.
This solution is not the best, but it's the simplest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<select>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
</select>

<input type="text"></input>

</body>
```

-

```
$('body').on('change', 'select', function() {
    $('input').val($(this).find(":selected").text()).select();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5C3Q9/2/ 
Just copy the text into a input field, so the user can select and copy it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve in modern browsers without Flash due to security restrains. You can check this site to review the options for jQuery:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-copy-clipboard-4-options/